# SharedPreference: Values are not saved with the very run of the first saving

Tags: sharedpreferences

for the first run of the app I use SharedPreference to save, that the app already has had the first run. But it needs a 2nd run to save the values correctly (other values needs also a 2nd run). After the 2nd run the app works correctly. The code snippet is in the onCreate of the activity (apply or commit makes no different)

```
    mPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);

    Log.d("onCreate", "KEY_FIRSTRUN 1 " + Boolean.toString(mPrefs.getBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN, true)));

    // First start
    if (mPrefs.getBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN, true))
    {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN, false).apply();
        Log.d("onCreate", "KEY_FIRSTRUN 2 " + Boolean.toString(mPrefs.getBoolean(KEY_FIRSTRUN, true)));

        // ... Initializing DB

    }else{
        // ...
    }
    int runCounter = mPrefs.getInt(KEY_COUNTER_RUN, 0) + 1;
    mPrefs.edit().putInt(KEY_COUNTER_RUN, runCounter).apply();

    Log.d("onCreate", "runCounter " + Integer.toString(mPrefs.getInt(KEY_COUNTER_RUN, 0)));
```

The Log.d output is:
onCreate: KEY_FIRSTRUN 1 true
onCreate: KEY_FIRSTRUN 2 false
onCreate: runCounter 1
onCreate: KEY_FIRSTRUN 1 true
onCreate: KEY_FIRSTRUN 2 false
onCreate: runCounter 1
onCreate: KEY_FIRSTRUN 1 false
onCreate: runCounter 2
onCreate: KEY_FIRSTRUN 1 false
onCreate: runCounter 3

PS: It doesn't work too with this code extensions like:

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.clear();...
```

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug: The value of another KEY-string was the same as KEY_FIRSTRUN, so the firstrun key was overwritten.